# Custom properties in jackson schema using multiple SchemaFactoryWrapper instances

Tags: java, jackson, jsonschema

I am using ValdationSchemaFactoryWarapper class to generate validation properties in JSON schema and I need to add my own custom properties to the schema too. If I develop my custom SchemaFactoryWrapper, I can only use one or the other but not the two at the same time.

I was able to achieve what I wanted by extending ValidationSchemaFactoryWrapper by using the below code, however, I was wondering whether there is perhaps a simpler way to do it, i.e. to use two separate instances of SchemaFactoryWrapper instances.

````
public class ConfigSchemaExtension {

    public static class ConfigSchemaFactoryWrapper extends ValidationSchemaFactoryWrapper {

        private static class SchemaFactoryWrapperFactory extends WrapperFactory {
            private SchemaFactoryWrapperFactory() {
            }

            public SchemaFactoryWrapper getWrapper(SerializerProvider p) {
                SchemaFactoryWrapper wrapper = new ConfigSchemaFactoryWrapper();
                wrapper.setProvider(p);
                return wrapper;
            }

            public SchemaFactoryWrapper getWrapper(SerializerProvider p, VisitorContext rvc) {
                SchemaFactoryWrapper wrapper = new ConfigSchemaFactoryWrapper();
                wrapper.setProvider(p);
                wrapper.setVisitorContext(rvc);
                return wrapper;
            }
        }

        public ConfigSchemaFactoryWrapper() {
            super(new AnnotationConstraintResolver());
            schemaProvider = new ConfigJsonSchemaFactory();
            visitorFactory = new FormatVisitorFactory(new SchemaFactoryWrapperFactory());
        }
    }

    public static class ConfigJsonSchemaFactory extends JsonSchemaFactory {
        @Override
        public com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.types.StringSchema stringSchema() {
            return new ConfigStringSchema();
        }
    }

    public static class ConfigStringSchema extends StringSchema {

        @JsonProperty
        private String myLink;

        @Override
        public void enrichWithBeanProperty(BeanProperty beanProperty) {
            super.enrichWithBeanProperty(beanProperty);
            Reference ref = beanProperty.getAnnotation(Reference.class);
            if(ref != null) this.myLink = ref.value(); 
        }
    }

    @Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @JacksonAnnotation
    public @interface Reference
    {
        String value() default "";
    }
}```
````